# Swift. Поиск строки на экране

Tags: ios, swift

Есть функция, которая создает рандомный текст `let s = randString()`.
Текст записывается в текстовое поле.

Как найти этот текст (переменную s на экране?)

Comment: записать в переменную, в какое именно поле передали текст

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
var viewToFind:UITextView;
for (_, item) in self.view.subviews.enumerate() {
    if(item is UITextView) {
        if((item as! UITextView).text == "test text") {
            viewToFind = item as! UITextView
            print(viewToFind.text)
        }
    }
}
```

пройдется по всем сабвью `self.view`, если вам надо искать дальше по дереву, то пишите рекурсию